# Preforming backward pass in network with batch normalization

Tags: machine-learning, backpropagation, batch-normalization

if we have a network model like this:
input_layer (linear) [0]
hidden_layer (linear) [1]
batchnorm1d() [2]
output_layer(linear) [3]

When preforming a backward pass would you calculate
$$\delta^3$$
then use this as the "input" to the backward pass in the batchnorm layer,
from this you get $$\delta^2$$
and again use this as "input" to the backward pass in the hidden layer and so on.

Or do you do the backward pass normally with the linear layers and then preform it seperate on the batchnorm layer?

Edit: The $$\delta^l$$ is the gradient of the weighted input of layer l.

Comment: Could you tell us what $\delta^3$ and $\delta^2$ refer to, so we don't have to guess?

Comment: Added it now, gradient of the weighted input of each layer